# why git-related error reported when running mlflow in python

Tags: python, git, spyder, mlflow

I'm new to mlflow and learning it from very beginning. I installed `mlflow` package in python, and run the following code in spyder.

```
import os
from random import random, randint

from mlflow import log_metric, log_param, log_artifacts

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Running mlflow_tracking.py")

    log_param("param1", randint(0, 100))

    log_metric("foo", random())
    log_metric("foo", random() + 1)
    log_metric("foo", random() + 2)

    if not os.path.exists("outputs"):
        os.makedirs("outputs")
    with open("outputs/test.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write("hello world!")

    log_artifacts("outputs")
```

This code should be standard and I run it for test. What makes me confused is that git-related error appears. No git connect is set up and no git file is called. Why is there such an error. By the way, I have `..\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin` in path (is `github` the same as `git` here).

```
WARNING mlflow.utils.git_utils: Failed to import Git (the Git executable is probably not on your PATH), so Git SHA is not available. Error: Failed to initialize: Bad git executable.
The git executable must be specified in one of the following ways:
    - be included in your $PATH
    - be set via $GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE
    - explicitly set via git.refresh()

All git commands will error until this is rectified.

This initial warning can be silenced or aggravated in the future by setting the
$GIT_PYTHON_REFRESH environment variable. Use one of the following values:
    - quiet|q|silence|s|none|n|0: for no warning or exception
    - warn|w|warning|1: for a printed warning
    - error|e|raise|r|2: for a raised exception

Example:
    export GIT_PYTHON_REFRESH=quiet

Running mlflow_tracking.py
```

I searched the following link to fix this error by setting `os.environ["GIT_PYTHON_REFRESH"] = "quiet"`.

[git executable not found in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48399498/git-executable-not-found-in-python)

Could anyone explain why it's this way and help to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `..\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin` does this contain the `git` exe? If not, you need to install Git for Windows on your system, I'd think.

Comment: @RandomDavis You are right. I install git and It's fixed now. But still have no idea how git is involved in this code.

Comment: Usually that's when some code wants to download some additional libraries or repos.